# PowerQuery filter on 20th of the month no matter the month or year

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to filter a list on the 20th of the month as this has been given as a significant date to identify a specific subset of records. There is no set date just a set day so it can be the 20th of any month in any year. Is there a way I can filter on these in PowerQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to filter a Table, choosing only to show the rows where the day = the 20th

Let's also also assume your data is loaded into Powerquery, and the date info is a column named **Date**

Add column, custom column, with formula
= Date.Day([Date])

( See the [Power Query M function reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference) list )

Click at top of that new column and use the drop down filter to [x] the 20

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Date.Day([Date])),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = 20))
in #"Filtered Rows"
```